# Multiple Subreports and multiple columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Wonder if anyone can assist. I have a report that down the left hand side needs to show multiple sub reports that flow one after the other. Down the right hand is another sub report that shows images that also needs to flow. So you end up with 1 column of data and column 2 of images. Both can change in length depending amount of rows in data and number of images. Can this be done?﻿

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done in Crystal reports, Place the reports in the order you want but you need to look at the performance as if number of sub reports increases then there is chance of performance degradation.

Comment: Thanks. Would I need to enter each Sub into its own group section or can they all be placed in one section? If in one section how would I make them flow one after each other without them overlappping.

Comment: create saperate section for all sub reports and place in individual sections.

Comment: Would that work for 2 columns of reports. The data being in column 1 in on set of sub reports and the images being in the 2nd column in a different sub report?

Comment: Thats possible but again it depends on how you want to view the reports.. If you want both sub reports in a single row to be in synx then you need to take extra care while linking the sub report to main report